# django - verifying data

Tags: django

in my django application, I allow users to cut and paste some json data into a textbox, to be uploaded to the database for saving.

I would like to verify the json data before saving them into my database. Do I have to write custom code to check every field or is there some form api I can use to check the data ?

Answer (score 2):

Create a form with validation methods

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

or use a model form:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are allowing user to enter (basically) arbitrary data care must be taken against [**SQL InJection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) or [**XSS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Django has support for both, here's how -

1. In your template, next to the form place a [**csrf_token**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) which prevents [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).
2. To prevent SQL Injection attacks, place [**urlencode filter**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode) in your templates wherever applicable. Well not much but it protects against cases like - turns your apostrophes ' into %27, rendering them harmless
3. Also if you have your form.py like `./app/form.py`, then while defining a form -

> ```
> class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
>     username  = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=30)
>     def clean_username(self):
>         username = self.cleaned_data['username']
>         # do any more processing you need.
> ```

1. Also if you are using JSON, then be sure to use [**inbuilt modules**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#id2) for this for the risk of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Downvoter, why not happy with this answer? Simply downvoting is not a good practice...

Comment: I wasnt the downvoter, but this is obviously wrong even without being familiar with Django. `csrf_token` protects against *CSRF*, not XSS, and `urlencode` does not sound like something that would protect against SQL Injection.

Comment: granted about first but the second need corrections - urlencode turns your apostrophes ' into %27, rendering them harmless...

Comment: you'd like to think so - but you'd be wrong. URL encoding and SQL escaping are different beasts, and have different rules - and as such, it is possible to be encoded by one and still evade the other.

Answer (score 1):

[If it decodes](http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-2.1.1/docs/index.html#encoders-and-decoders), then I guess it's json...

However one wonders why you'd put that straight into your database without parsing it? Are you planning to do something like serve it straight back to them later?  If so then you can [validate it client side](http://www.jsonlint.com/).